# Angular, dúvida como setar checkbox

Tags: angularjs

Galera, preciso de um help, tenho um checkbox que quando selecionado ativa uma classe na , até aqui funciona, problema quando duplico a tr, ele ativa a classe para as duas ao mesmo tempo.

Postei o link no jsfiddle, se alguém puder ajudar agradeço!

https://jsfiddle.net/samucsouza/sgg5mhu7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, o motivo de você não ter obtido o resultado esperado, ocorre porque seus checkbox estão no mesmo escopo.

Uma maneira de resolver seria isolar o escopo do mesmo. Portando provavelmente você vai ter um ng-repeat, então você pode usar o objeto em si para setar a classe.

Por exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/sgg5mhu7/4/

Comment: Obrigado Mario pela dica, deu certo, valeu abs!